# How to get SUM of a column in PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get Summation of a column from my database table. But I get just 0.00. My codes are:

```
$total_income_query = $db->prepare("select sum(credit) from accounts WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(:endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')");

$stmt->bindParam(':startDate',$startDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':endDate',$endDate);
$stmt->execute();

$total = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo $total_income = $total[0];
```

It supposed to echo 306700.80. I've checked the query. It works fine in Database but not in my PHP script. What's wrong with it?

Comment: try with `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: **Show us what is in `$startDate` and `$endDate`**

Comment: `WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(:endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')` you changed the value in the date column to some text not looking like a date. And therefor you cannot compare that to the start en enddate anymore

Comment: try  `sum(credit) as total` and change `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`  and get `$total['total]`

Comment: @NiravJoshi Thats not really going to change anything is it

Comment: Now it shows "Undefined offset: 0" @NiravJoshi

Comment: try with @urfusion 's code

Comment: Add some error checking!!!! Your query is wrong

Comment: btw: if you press enter to spread your query in line 1 over several lines, it would gain a lot of readability

Comment: @RiggsFolly if (isset($_POST['startDate'])) { $startDate = $_POST['startDate'];}
  if (isset($_POST['endDate'])) {  $endDate = $_POST['endDate'];}

Comment: $startDate and $endDate works fine. They contain "01/05/2017" and "31/05/2017" @RiggsFolly

Comment: @urfusion Now it shows " Undefined index: total"

Comment: IF the `date` column is a MYSQL DATE type column then `WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') 
               AND STR_TO_DATE(:endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')` the date mask is not necessary and is as I said earlier WRONG because a MYSQL DATE is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: unless he stores the date as a varchar (what is not logical). however the query would not give an error reformating that date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was with my PDO code. I supposed to write $total_income_query instead of $stmt. The code should look like this...

```
$total_income_query = $db->prepare("select sum(credit) from accounts WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(:endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')");

$total_income_query->bindParam(':startDate',$startDate);
$total_income_query->bindParam(':endDate',$endDate);
$total_income_query->execute();

$total = $total_income_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo $total_income = $total[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: my explaining was wrong, i think. But is remains coming to do not reformat your date in the database. 
That is: I suppose you store your date in columns of the type DATE/DATETIME

```
<?php
$total_income_query = $db->prepare("
    SELECT SUM(credit) 
    from accounts 
    WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:startDate, '%d/%m/%Y') 
               AND STR_TO_DATE(:endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')");

$stmt->bindParam(':startDate',$startDate);
$stmt->bindParam(':endDate',$endDate);
$stmt->execute();

$total = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo $total_income = $total[0];
```

Comment: But it works fine in Database. I just checked it again. "select sum(debit) as total from accounts where STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('31/05/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')"

Comment: Type of date column is Varchar

Comment: tell us what type is the column Date, and if not DATE: how do you store the information?

Comment: a varchar..... It is a date, so type DATE would have had advantages. What does the string in your varchar look like?

Comment: It stores like "01/05/2017"

Comment: @KallolDas Is it too late to undo your mistake and change that column to a more sensible MYSQL DATE

Comment: The query works fine with mysql_query. But it's creating problem with PDO. I think there is something wrong with my PDO code.

Comment: should the table get filled with a lot of records: for this query the database will have to reformat the varchar to another format and compare it to the values to see if it is between. Had it been a DATE, it does not need to modify and will be able to use an index on it and be able to quickly see if a date is before or after, say, 2017-01-01. IT will never be a quick query